# How to check if a record already exist in column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a column `index[0]`

How can I know if value I entered already exists in this column and increase the existent `row["Quantity"]`

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
      {
          //some code
      }
 }
```

Comment: What do you use as datasource?

Comment: i mean when typing in datagride view before inserting

Comment: hey i am in entering data level no datasource yet  !

Answer (score 0):

```
//check if the value in  same column is repeated dataGridView1:

for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Value.ToString())
            {
                //you can increase  row["Quantity"] here 
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: not from textbox to datagride view i wanna check same column recourds

Comment: I don't know your exact requirement. Hope this will help you. Edited my answere

Comment: for example i am type in column 
`ItemNum  ItemName ItemQuantity
   1        tea         1 
   2        item        4 `
if i type '1' again only increase tea quantity of exist row

Comment: @KOKO the above code will check if the value in  same column is repeated dataGridView1. Can be used after you enter anything in any column